# SwiftUI System Cursor

Tags: swift, swiftui, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to change the cursor to a crosshair in **SwiftUI** on **MacOS**.

I've put the following code into the `AppDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` function:

```
NSCursor.crosshair.set()
```

When the application loads, I see the cursor change to the crossHair, and then swap straight back to the standard pointer.

It would be great to hear what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 31):

It is not the way how `NSCursor` works. There is a stack of cursors so any standard (or non-standard) control can push own type of cursor on top and make that cursor current. So you just place first cursor, but then some standard view having own default cursor replaces it.

As SwiftUI does not allow now to manage cursors natively, the solution might be

a) either to set/push desired cursor on SwiftUI view appear/disappear, or

b) add cursor rect to `NSHostingController` view using standard `NSView.addCursorRect` method.

**Update:** some quick demo from existing project (part of custom button solution)

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoCustomCursor: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Cross Button")
                .padding(20)
                .background(Color.blue)
        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .onHover { inside in
            if inside {
                NSCursor.crosshair.push()
            } else {
                NSCursor.pop()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for your help with this. Might it be possible to see an example of your suggestion using NSHostingController? I've had a play around, but can't seem to work it out! I tried setting / pushing the cursor in .onAppear, but it didn't seem to make a difference to the outcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This gets me 90% of the way there, but unfortunately clicking the button wipes out the cursor -- seems to be when the button changes content. Couldn't get it to work with any combination of hover, onTapGesture, etc.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when combined with a DragGesture. The gesture will reset the cursor.

Comment: Same same. Unable to find a way to stop the resize cursor from changing back to an arrow during the resize in SwiftUI.

Comment: Looks like the same pre-SwiftUI problem as http://cocoadev.github.io/CursorFlashingProblems/

Adding `NSApp.windows[0].disableCursorRects()` at the start of the DragGesture and `NSApp.windows[0].enableCursorRects()` in `.onEnded` fixes the problem for me here.

Except `NSApp.windows[0]` isn't always the front window. Darn.

 `NSApp.windows.forEach { $0.disableCursorRects() }`  works though. ;)

Comment: NSApp.keyWindow?.disableCursorRects() should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Swift Playground code to illustrate the problem:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    SplitView().frame(width: 600, height:600).border(Color.black)
)

struct SplitView: View {
    @State var position: CGFloat = 10.0
    var body: some View {
        Text("top")
            .frame(height: position)
        PaneDivider(position: $position)
        Text("bottom")
        Spacer()
    }
}

struct PaneDivider: View {
    @Binding var position: CGFloat
    @GestureState private var isDragging = false // Will reset to false when dragging has ended
       
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().frame(height:10).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        .onHover { inside in
            if !isDragging {
                if inside { NSCursor.resizeUpDown.push() }
                else {  NSCursor.pop() }
                }
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { position += $0.translation.height  }
            .updating($isDragging) { (value, state, transaction) in
                if !state { NSCursor.resizeUpDown.push() } // This is overridden, something else in the system is pushing the arrow cursor during the drag
                state = true
            }
            .onEnded { _ in NSCursor.pop() })
    }
}
```

Setting a breakpoint on -[NSCursor set] shows it firing constantly during the drag in

```
Setting a breakpoint on -[NSCursor set] shows it firing constantly during the drag in
  * frame #0: 0x00000001a48c2944 AppKit`-[NSCursor set]
    frame #1: 0x00000001a491cc4c AppKit`forwardMethod + 200
    frame #2: 0x00000001a491cc4c AppKit`forwardMethod + 200
    frame #3: 0x00000001a4924428 AppKit`-[NSView cursorUpdate:] + 132
    frame #4: 0x00000001a48cb2e4 AppKit`-[NSWindow(NSCursorRects) _setCursorForMouseLocation:] + 432
    frame #5: 0x00000001a47f0d70 AppKit`_NSWindowDisplayCycleUpdateStructuralRegions + 544
    frame #6: 0x00000001a47ec028 AppKit`__NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserverForUpdateStructuralRegions_block_invoke + 428
    frame #7: 0x00000001a47e59ec AppKit`NSDisplayCycleObserverInvoke + 188
    frame #8: 0x00000001a47e5568 AppKit`NSDisplayCycleFlush + 832
    frame #9: 0x00000001a81a8544 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) + 120
    frame #10: 0x00000001a81a754c QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 336
    frame #11: 0x00000001a488e6e0 AppKit`__62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 304
    frame #12: 0x00000001a4fe2a10 AppKit`___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 64
    frame #13: 0x00000001a1f28e14 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
    frame #14: 0x00000001a1f28c60 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 572
    frame #15: 0x00000001a1f281a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 764
    frame #16: 0x00000001a1f27734 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    frame #17: 0x00000001a9e25b84 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    frame #18: 0x00000001a9e258f8 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 552
    frame #19: 0x00000001a9e256b8 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
    frame #20: 0x00000001a47114ec AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 836
    frame #21: 0x00000001a470fe8c AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1292
    frame #22: 0x00000001a4701d18 AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 596
    frame #23: 0x00000001a46d3728 AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 1064
    frame #24: 0x00000001c25f11b4 SwiftUI`generic specialization <SwiftUI.TestingAppDelegate> of function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Existential To Protocol Constrained Generic> of SwiftUI.runApp(__C.NSApplicationDelegate) -> Swift.Never + 96
    frame #25: 0x00000001c2e34ba0 SwiftUI`SwiftUI.runApp<τ_0_0 where τ_0_0: SwiftUI.App>(τ_0_0) -> Swift.Never + 220
    frame #26: 0x00000001c29de854 SwiftUI`static SwiftUI.App.main() -> () + 128
    frame #27: 0x0000000100c8c540 Calculator`static CalculatorApp.$main(self=Calculator.CalculatorApp) at CalculatorApp.swift:5:1
    frame #28: 0x0000000100c8c5e0 Calculator`main at CalculatorApp.swift:0
    frame #29: 0x00000001a1e48420 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Looks like the same pre-SwiftUI problem as http://cocoadev.github.io/CursorFlashingProblems/

Adding `NSApp.windows[0].disableCursorRects()` at the start of the DragGesture and `NSApp.windows[0].enableCursorRects()` in `.onEnded` fixes the problem for me here.

Except `NSApp.windows[0]` isn't always the front window. Darn. `NSApp.windows.forEach { $0.disableCursorRects() }` works though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Been trying to solve this and this page keeps coming up. So I thought I'd post my solution

```swift
import SwiftUI

public struct HoverCursorModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @State var isHovered: Bool = false
    
    let pointerImage : NSImage
    
    init(imageName: String){
        self.pointerImage = NSImage(named: imageName) ?? NSImage()
    }
    
    init(systemSymbolName: String){
        self.pointerImage = NSImage(systemSymbolName: systemSymbolName , accessibilityDescription: nil) ?? NSImage()
    }
    
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        content
            .onHover { isHovered in
                self.isHovered = isHovered
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    if self.isHovered {
                        // Looks like ugly hack, but otherwise cursor gets reset to standard arrow.
                        // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984079/7964697 for details.
                        NSApp.windows.forEach { $0.disableCursorRects() }
                        NSCursor(image: pointerImage, hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 9, y: 9)).push()
                    } else {
                        NSCursor.pop()
                        NSApp.windows.forEach { $0.enableCursorRects() }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        
    }
    
}
```

Usage

Just add this to your button if you want to use an SF Font

```swift
.modifier(HoverCursorModifier(systemSymbolName: "hand.point.up.fill"))
```

or this to use an image in your resources

```swift
.modifier(HoverCursorModifier(imageName: "<YOUR IMAGE NAME GOES HERE>"))
```

I would recommend using styles for buttons. You can add the modifier to a style so all your buttons get the same hover effect. For example

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct StylePrimaryButton: ButtonStyle  {
    
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration) -> some View {
        PrimaryButton(configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    struct PrimaryButton: View {
        
        let configuration: ButtonStyle.Configuration
        @Environment(\.isEnabled) private var isEnabled: Bool
       
        var body: some View {
            
            configuration.label
                .padding(10)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(.black)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : isEnabled ? 1 : 0.5)
                .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.2), value: configuration.isPressed)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .modifier(HoverCursorModifier(systemSymbolName: "hand.point.up.fill"))
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

and then just do this to your buttons

```swift
Button {
    // DO Something
} label: {
    Text("Hello World")
}
.buttonStyle(StylePrimaryButton())
```

Answer (score 0):

`onHover` doesn't exist in macCatalyst, but you can add it yourself. The alternative solution is explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/60748101/1450348

Answer (score 0):

Like **Avitzur** mentioned in the comments, there is a flashing problem that makes the cursor change to the default value (especially if you have some animation that happens when hovering on the view), I have done the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI

 enum CursorEvent {
    case hover
    case drag
 }

 extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func cursor(
        _ cursor: NSCursor,
        on event: CursorEvent = .hover,
        shouldKeepDefaultCursor: Bool = false,
        currentWindow: NSWindow = << Pass your default window >>
    ) -> some View {
        if shouldKeepDefaultCursor {
            self
        } else {
            switch event {
            case .hover:
                self.onHover { isInside in
                    isInside ? cursor.enable(on: currentWindow) : cursor.disable(on: currentWindow)
                }
            case .drag:
                self.simultaneousGesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { _ in
                            cursor.enable(on: currentWindow)
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            cursor.disable(on: currentWindow)
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
 }

 extension NSCursor {
    fileprivate func enable(on window: NSWindow) {
        window.disableCursorRects()
        self.push()
    }

    fileprivate func disable(on window: NSWindow) {
        NSCursor.pop()
        window.enableCursorRects()
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```swift
 Button("Click Me") {
   print("Button Clicked")
 }
 .cursor(.pointingHand)
```

Comment: Your usage isn't realistic, what window should you provide for currentWindow?

Comment: Why isn't realistic? currentWindow is the "keyWindow" that the user is using.