# SwiftUI macOS hover on Button change cursor mouse

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, hover

I have a `Button` as seen in the code below, I would like when the mouse passed over the `Button` the cursor would change as if to mean that it is clickable.

Is there anything like this?

Version:

```
macOs: 10.15.4
Xcode: 11.7
```

Code:

```
Button(action: { ... }) {
   ImageMac(systemName: "heart")
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

AppDelegate:

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var popover = NSPopover.init()
    var statusBar: StatusBarController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()
        
        popover.contentViewController = MainViewController()
        popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 360, height: 360)
        popover.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        
        // Create the Status Bar Item with the Popover
        statusBar = StatusBarController.init(popover)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61985678/12299030?

Comment: I had tried, but it doesn't seem to work on my project.

Comment: @Asperi: From what I understand the problem seems to derive that I am using inside the statusBar inside a popover, it seems that there is not working.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I recall status bar item panels cannot be key window, but on hover works only with key windows.

Comment: @Asperi: So there is currently no solution?

Comment: @Paul did you end up finding any solution? I have the same problem. No hover effect on a view inside a popover