# SwiftUI - change cursor

Tags: macos, swiftui

**Edit: This works correct as mentioned by @Asperi. I need to use a View / Control, not a shape**

I'm trying to change the cursor to a pointer when I hover over an element.
I looked at this, but it doesn't work for me
[SwiftUI System Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984959/swiftui-system-cursor)

This is my code

```
struct CursorTestView: View {
    @State private var hover: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(hover ? Color.green : Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                .onHover(perform: { hovering in
                    self.hover = hovering
                    if (hover) {
                        NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
                    } else {
                        NSCursor.pop()
                    }
                })
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2))
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to what I'm missing ?

Thanks

Comment: The solution from referenced post still works. Tested with Xcode 12.5 / macOS 11.3. Probably it does because of used Button which is a control. So try to use Button (maybe we custom style) instead of just a shape/view.

Comment: Ahh - yes, it works for button. I assumed it would work for all types of views ( working mainly with webapp I guess I'm spoiled ). Edit: Just realized RoundedRectangle is a Shape, not a View

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice the view is rendering 2 times so use the main queue.

```
struct CursorTestView: View {
    
    @State private var hover: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(hover ? Color.green : Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                .onHover { isHovered in
                    self.hover = isHovered
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { //<-- Here
                        if (self.hover) {
                            NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
                        } else {
                            NSCursor.pop()
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2))
    }
}
```

It will also work if you do not update hover var.

[image]

Comment: Wow - posting to main works for shapes. Awesome, but strange that it is required.
Oh, so updating the @State var is causing the re-render and that is why it needs to be posted ?

Comment: yes. I think updating the  @State creates the problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me in macOS 14.0 either, I needed an onChange(of: hover) and pushing the cursor there inside DispatchQueue.main.async (or Task)